# Nested themable components: apply styles depending on a theme class of the nearest themed parent, ignoring deeper parents bearing theme classes

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors, themes, css-specificity

I have components that can be themed:

```html
<div class="ComponentFoo theme-blue">
</div>
```

Components can be nested into one another.

**I want a theme applied to a parent component propagate to all its children**.

A naive implementation could look like this:

```html
<div class="ComponentFoo theme-blue">
  <div class="ComponentBar">
    <div class="ComponentBaz">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="ComponentBar">
  </div>

  <div class="ComponentBar">
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.theme-blue.ComponentFoo,
.theme-blue .ComponentFoo {
  background-color: blue;
}

.theme-blue.ComponentBar,
.theme-blue .ComponentBar {
  color: white;
}
```

This works well for a simple case, but fails miserably when themes are nested:

```html
<div class="ComponentFoo theme-red">
  <div class="ComponentBar theme-blue">
    <div class="ComponentBaz">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.theme-blue.ComponentBaz,
.theme-blue .ComponentBaz {
  border-color: blue,
  color: blue,
  background-color: white;
}

.theme-red.ComponentBaz,
.theme-red .ComponentBaz {
  border-color: red,
  color: red,
  background-color: white;
}
```

In this case, I expect `ComponentBaz` to assume the blue theme because the nearest themed parent is blue. But that's not what happens!

This is because both `.theme-blue .ComponentBaz` and `.theme-red .ComponentBaz` selectors match the Baz component. CSS does not care about the depth of nesting.

When both selectors match, it is the order of declarations in CSS code that matters: last one wins.

---

I can imagine fixing this in the following ways:

1. Using extremely numerous and verbose selectors exploiting the `>` parent combinator and something to override CSS specifity, so that `.theme-red > *` wins over `.theme-red > * > *`, etc.

   I don't like this solution because it would make CSS unreadable.
2. Use programming/templating to pass a parent's theme into all of its children:

   ```html
   <ComponentFoo @theme="red" as |theme|>
     <ComponentBar @theme={{theme}}>
       <ComponentBaz @theme="blue" as |theme2|>
         <ComponentQuux @theme={{theme2}}/>
       </ComponentBaz>
     </ComponentBar>
   </ComponentFoo>
   ```

   I don't like this solution because it's also quite verbose and introduces too much coupling.
3. Simply apply the theme HTML class to each themable component explicitly.

   This is what I'm doing, but I don't see it a solution. More like a workaround, a lesser of evils.

---

**What are the more elegant ways of achieving this? I want a pure CSS solution that would let me use an HTML class on a parent, so that it applies styles to children and overrides grand-parents' styles.**

Since CSS is very limited, we are using the Sass preprocessor. I wouldn't mind using a solution producing messy CSS if it is abstracted away very elegantly with Sass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are setting too many rules in your CSS.

Why don't you set the selector just for the themes, and leave inheritance do the job ?

```css
.theme-blue {
  border-color: blue;
  color: blue;
  background-color: white;
}

.theme-red  {
  border-color: red;
  color: red;
  background-color: white;
}

div {
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="ComponentFoo theme-red">I am red
  <div class="ComponentBar theme-blue">I am blue
    <div class="ComponentBaz">I am nested
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="ComponentFoo theme-blue">I am blue
  <div class="ComponentBar theme-red">I am red
    <div class="ComponentBaz">I am nested
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Alternative solution using CSS constants

```css
.theme-blue {
  --border-color: blue;
  --color: blue;
  --background-color: white;
}

.theme-red  {
  --border-color: red;
  --color: red;
  --background-color: white;
}

.ComponentFoo, .ComponentBar, .ComponentBaz {
  border-color: var(--border-color);
  color: var(--color);
  background-color: var(--background-color);
}

.other {
  border-color: black;
  color: green;
  background-color: silver;
}

div {
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="ComponentFoo theme-red">I am red
  <div class="ComponentBar theme-blue">I am blue
     <div class="other">other
        <div class="ComponentBaz">I am nested
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="ComponentFoo theme-blue">I am blue
  <div class="ComponentBar theme-red">I am red
     <div class="other">other
        <div class="ComponentBaz">I am nested
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Of course, you can add another class, "themable", and change the selector with .ComponentFoo .ComponentBar .ComponentBaz to ".themable"

How does this work:

In the theme-blue class you define values for CSS constants (some people call it CSS variables). This values are propagated following the cascading rules, so all the children and descendants will have the same values. But, as  all the CSS inheritance, if a child redeclares this values, the children of the child will inherit the redeclared values.

All that is needed now is to set the standard CSS properties to this inherited values, that is done using the var() syntax

Comment: Because I have no idea what exact styles and elements various components are gonna have. PS Upvoted.

Comment: @AndreyMikhaylov-lolmaus if you do not know which styles you want to apply to cascading elements inside a .theme-* class element how do you want to to that without definining specific classes with styles? sounds like you want to push a relative solution into a absolute problem. thanks

Comment: Have you checked my second snippet ? I would like to know if it solves your problem.

Comment: OMG, yes it does!!! But I don't understand how. Why does this work differently for CSS variables than for actual styles? Please provide a detailed explanation and I will accept your answer!! ‍♀️

Answer (score 1):

By going through your question, I think you want to select a child but not the grandchild. For that, in CSS we have `>` selector.

**For example:**

```
.test_class_1 > .test_class_2
```

Here it will select the child with class `test_class_2` but it will not select the grandchild that is inside the `test_class_2` div.

According to this, I modified your css a little bit:

```
.theme-blue>.ComponentBaz,
.theme-blue>.ComponentBaz {
  border-color: blue;
  color: blue;
  background-color: white;
}

.theme-red>.ComponentBaz,
.theme-red>.ComponentBar {
  border-color: red;
  color: red;
  background-color: white;
}
```

Here I added `>` which selects div with `ComponentBaz` as a class but **not** the div inside this div. I also replaced "," with ";" maybe that was just typo.

Here is the JSfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/o20dLy7k/

Comment: Is there a way to adjust this solution to allow for arbitrary nesting? So that styles with shallower nesting win over styles with deeper nesting?

Answer (score 0):

If you can limit `css` to theme `background`, component `color` and `border` then you're in luck.
Everything can be simplified to 2 colours - in my snippet the first drawing lblue and black - there are only 3 delicate situations and they all are delicate only because of visibility of the text:

- theme light-blue + component light-blue (or black and black)
- inherited light-blue theme + component light-blue
- theme light-blue + inherited component light-blue

No more worries. Seriously, everything works as a charm and [validator](https://validator.w3.org/unicorn/) is green, has no comments.
The first drawing - 2 colors - a test of possible worries, the second ugly, but informative - a dozen colors in various combinations. I used `::before{ content: attr(class)}` for content, so my css looks worse than usual.
I decided, that very, very complicated situations - as in the center of the drawing - did not deserve to have their text colour corrected (special treatment changed the legacy), too much code. If you wish, you can use something different than `color` and the problem will be gone.
Of course used colours must visible differ each to other.

```js
function switcher(){
    var element = document.getElementById("body");
    if(element.classList){  element.classList.toggle("shadow");}
    else{
        var classes = element.className.split(" ");
        var i = classes.indexOf("shadow");
        if(i >= 0)  classes.splice(i, 1);
        else    classes.push("shadow");
        element.className = classes.join(" ");}}
```

```css
body{ color: #000}
p, span, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, div::before{ background: #fff}
    /* themes */
.shadow .black{ background: #000;   color: #fff}
.black{ background: #000;}
.red{   background: #f00;}
.green{ background: #0d0;}
.blue{  background: #00f}
.white{ background: #fff}
.gold{  background: gold}
.purple{    background: purple}
.grey{  background: grey}
.teal{  background: teal}
.lblue{ background: #5ae}
    /* components */
.Cblack{    border-color: black;        color: black}
.Cred{  border-color: red;      color: red}
.Cgreen{    border-color: green;    color: green}
.Cblue{ border-color: blue;     color: blue}
.Cwhite{    border-color: white;        color: white}
.Cgold{ border-color: gold;     color: gold}
.Cpurple{   border-color: purple;   color: purple}
.Cteal{ border-color: teal;     color: teal}
.Clblue{    border-color: #5ae;     color: #5ae}
.Cwhite::before, .Cwhite>::before{ background: #aaa}
    /* shadow */
.shadow .lblue .Clblue::before, .shadow .red .Cred::before, .shadow .green .Cgreen::before, .shadow .blue .Cblue::before, .shadow .white .Cwithe::before, .shadow .gold .Cgold::before, .shadow .purple .Cpurple::before, .shadow .grey .Cgrey::before, .shadow .teal .Cteal::before, .shadow .black .Cblack::before,
.shadow .Clblue .lblue::before, .shadow .Cred .red::before, .shadow .Cgreen .green::before, .shadow .Cblue .blue::before, .shadow .Cwhite .withe::before, .shadow .Cgold .gold::before, .shadow .Cpurple .purple::before, .shadow .Cgrey .grey::before, .shadow .Cteal .teal::before, .shadow .Cblack .black::before, 
.shadow .lblue.Clblue::before, .shadow .red.Cred::before, .shadow .green.Cgreen::before, .shadow .blue.Cblue::before, .shadow .white.Cwhite::before, .shadow .gold.Cgold::before, .shadow .purple.Cpurple::before, .shadow .grey.Cgrey::before, .shadow .teal.Cteal::before, .shadow .black.Cblack::before{
border: 1px dotted black; 
text-shadow: -1px 0 1px black, 0 1px 1px black, 1px 0 1px black, 0 -1px 1px black;}
.shadow .black .Cblack::before, .shadow .Cblack .black::before, .shadow .black.Cblack::before{
border: 1px dotted white;
text-shadow: -1px 0 1px white, 0 1px 1px white, 1px 0 1px white, 0 -1px 1px white}
.shadow ::before, .shadow p, .shadow span, .shadow h4{ background: 0}
    /* for snippet only */
button{ position: fixed; top: 45vh; right: 0; background: #acf; border: 12px solid white; color: black; padding: 25px; border-radius: 50%; outline: 0}
div{ margin: 10px 8px; padding: 10px 8px; border: 3px solid transparent;}
div::before{ content: attr(class); border-radius: 8px}
p, span, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, div::before{ padding: 2px 8px;}
```

```html
<body id="body" class="x">

<div class="lblue Clblue"><h4>h4</h4><p>paragraph</p><span>span</span>
<div class="Cblack">
<div class="black">
<div class="Cblack">
<div class="Clblue">
<div class="lblue">
<div class="Cblack"><h4>h4</h4><p>paragraph</p><span>span</span>
<div class="Clblue"><h4>h4</h4><p>paragraph</p><span>span</span></div>
<div class="black"><h4>h4</h4><p>paragraph</p><span>span</span>
</div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div>

<div class="red Cgold">
<div class="black">
<div class="black Cblack">
<div class="red Cblack">
<div class="green">
<div class="blue ">
<div class="white ">
</div></div></div>
<div class="gold ">
<div class="purple ">
<div class="grey Cred"><h4>h4</h4><p>paragraph</p><span>span</span>
<div class="teal ">
<div class="white Cwhite">
</div></div></div>
<div class="teal Cteal">
<div class="white Cwhite">
<div class="blue">
<div class="black Cteal">
<div class="grey Cred">
</div></div></div>
<div class="Cpurple"><h4>h4</h4><p>paragraph</p><span>span</span>
<div class="Cred"><h4>h4</h4><p>paragraph</p><span>span</span>
<div class="Cgold"><h4>h4</h4><p>paragraph</p><span>span</span>
</div></div></div>
<div class="green">
<div class="white Cgreen">
<div class="red Cred"><h4>h4</h4><p>paragraph</p><span>span</span>
<div class="Cwhite"><h4>h4</h4><p>paragraph</p><span>span</span>
</div></div></div>
</div></div></div>
</div></div></div>
</div></div></div>

<button onclick="switcher()"><b>switch</b></button></body>
```

---

**suplement**
If you can make sure, that text will always be served inside a tag, forget about shadows

```
p, span, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6{ background: #fff}
```

If you can exclude too bright colours - this is it. If not... exceptions...
I added this to the snippet, with exception for `.Cwhite::before`

Answer (score 0):

You need to be sure of what you mean.  If you mean Themes in the traditional sense, *these solutions will introduce a hard to find bug!*.   If more than one rule matches, then all properties not in common between the rules wll apply.  For example, imagine a dark theme changing foreground and background and and neon theme changing foreground and color palette.  The background (from dark) and the color palette (from neon) would apply regardless of order.

One solution is to regularize your themes such that each themes sets all properties set by any theme.